# MySQL: Returning Counts (*) with NULL or 0 Vales

Tags: mysql, sql, count, null

I have  three tables CustomerSales & Icecream. For the purpose of understanding there is one ice cream in each sales.

**CustomerSales** Table contains (CustomerId, PurchaseId, postcode, IcecreamID)

**Ice_Cream** contains (Ice_Cream Name, Ice_Cream Id)

I'm trying to write a query which returns the amount of sales of chocolate Ice-cream to every postcode (zipcode), but I also want to know which postcodes had zero sales. Currently it's only returning the postcodes that had sales.

```
SELECT C.postcode, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL SALES
FROM CustomerSales C JOIN IceCream I
ON C.icecreamID = I.id AND
WHERE I.name = "Chocolate" AND C.saleyear = "2019"
GROUP BY C.postcode;
```

This is close to what I want but only includes the postcodes that made sales. I also want to include the postcodes that made 0 sales of chocolate icecream in 2019.

How would I do that? I've tried with rollup but think I'm doing it incorrectly.

I was also thinking

```
SELECT C.postcode, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL SALES
FROM CustomerSales C OUTER LEFT JOIN IceCream I
ON C.icecreamID = I.id AND
WHERE I.name = "Chocolate" AND C.saleyear = "2019"
GROUP BY C.postcode;
```

I think the issue is, counts return the values of rows.

Answer (score 2):

Count the PurchaseId, instead of *, I think this should return the expected results:

```
SELECT C.postcode, COUNT(C.PurchaseId) AS TOTAL SALES
FROM CustomerSales C OUTER LEFT JOIN IceCream I
ON C.icecreamID = I.id AND
WHERE I.name = "Chocolate" AND C.saleyear = "2019"
GROUP BY C.postcode;
```

Comment: `AND WHERE` is not valid syntax, so it is rather mysterious that this answer is accepted.

Comment: True, I should have paid more attention. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT C.postcode, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_SALES
FROM CustomerSales C JOIN IceCream I
ON C.icecreamID = I.id AND
WHERE I.name = "Chocolate" AND C.saleyear = "2019"
GROUP BY C.postcode

union

select c.postcode, '0' as TOTAL_SALES
FROM CUSTOMERSALES C 
where c.postcode not in(select cs.postcode from 
FROM CustomerSales C JOIN IceCream I
ON C.icecreamID = I.id AND
WHERE I.name = "Chocolate" AND C.saleyear = "2019"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem I see is you are doing a join and then counting number of records returned so by default records that do not have sales do not end in the join.

Join type is important here I think LEFT JOIN will show all data from first table even if no data is found in joined table, and then you will count fields from joined table, which will return NULL if none are found

Something like this:

```
SELECT C.postcode, COUNT(I.name) AS TOTAL SALES
FROM CustomerSales C LEFT JOIN IceCream I
ON C.icecreamID = I.id AND
WHERE I.name = "Chocolate" AND C.saleyear = "2019"
GROUP BY C.postcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want *ALL* the postcodes then you must do a `LEFT` join of the `DISTINCT` postcodes to `CustomerSales` and then to `IceCream`:

```
SELECT p.postcode, COUNT(C.PurchaseId) AS TOTAL_SALES
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT postcode
  FROM CustomerSales
) p LEFT JOIN CustomerSales C 
ON C.postcode = p.postcode AND C.saleyear = '2019'
LEFT JOIN IceCream I ON C.icecreamID = I.id AND I.name = 'Chocolate'
GROUP BY p.postcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you want to use a `LEFT JOIN`, move the condition on `I` to the `ON` clause and change the `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT C.postcode, COUNT(i.id) AS TOTAL SALES
FROM CustomerSales C LEFT JOIN
     IceCream I
     ON C.icecreamID = I.id AND
        I.name = 'Chocolate'
WHERE C.saleyear = 2019
GROUP BY C.postcode;
```